# what is the deep meaning of this Gita quote?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

The verses 67-68 from Gita chapter 2 are given below:

**Indriyaanaam hi charataam yanmanuvidheeyate**

**Tadasya harati prajnyaam vaayurnaavamivaambhasi**

what is the deep meaning of this Gita quote ?

Comment: This verse is part of the the answer to the query of Arjun in Gita 2.54, "how does an enlightened person behaves in the world?" The metaphysics of any being's soul is that it is connected to the world through body senses via mind. Every being on the earth is born with a destiny to be fulfilled, but delusion of Maya makes a normal person to forget and delay the destiny, its course, its real Self, due to attachment to material senses which is explained in 2.67. Only when a yogi subdues his/her senses like a tortoise withdraws its limbs(2.58), he/she becomes aware of Self in enlightenment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sloka 67 of Chapter 2 of BG relates to pure SPIRITUAL aspects.

If we start with Sloka 62 of Chapter 2 of BG, we can understand that they are related to PURE SPIRITUAL aspects, meant for persons proposing to be/already engaged in SPIRITUAL pursuits.

> ध्यायतो विषयान्पुंसः सङ्गस्तेषूपजायते।
>
> सङ्गात् संजायते कामः कामात्क्रोधोऽभिजायते।।2.62।।
>
> In the case of a person who dwells on objects, there arises attachment
> for them. From attachment grows hankering, from hankering springs
> anger.
>
> क्रोधाद्भवति संमोहः संमोहात्स्मृतिविभ्रमः।
>
> स्मृतिभ्रंशाद् बुद्धिनाशो बुद्धिनाशात्प्रणश्यति।।2.63।।
>
> From anger follows delusion; from delusion, failure of memory; from
> failure of memory, the loss of understanding; from the loss of
> understanding, he perishes.
>
> नास्ति बुद्धिरयुक्तस्य न चायुक्तस्य भावना।
>
> न चाभावयतः शान्तिरशान्तस्य कुतः सुखम्।।2.66।।
>
> The man who cannot fix his mind in meditation cannot have knowledge of
> the Self. The unsteady man cannot practise meditation. He cannot have
> even intense devotion to Self knowledge nor can he have burning longing
> for liberation or Moksha.

> He who does not practise meditation cannot
> possess peace of mind. How can the man who has no peace of mind enjoy
> happiness?

> Desire or Trishna (thirsting for sense objects) is the enemy
> of peace. There cannot be an iota or tinge of happiness for a man who
> is thirsting for sensual objects. The mind will be ever restless? and
> will be hankering for the objects. Only when this thirsting dies? does
> man enjoy peace. Only then can he meditate and rest in the Self.

Then comes the sloka 67.

> इन्द्रियाणां हि चरतां यन्मनोऽनुविधीयते।
>
> तदस्य हरति प्रज्ञां वायुर्नावमिवाम्भसि।।2.67।।
>
> That mind, which is allowed by a person to be submissive to, i.e.,
> allowed to go after the senses which go on operating, i.e.,
> experiencing sense-objects, such a mind loses its inclination towards
> the pure self. The meaning is that it gets inclined towards
> sense-objects. Just as a contrary wind forcibly carries away a ship
> moving on the waters, in the name manner wisdom also is carried away
> from such a mind. [The idea is that the pursuit of sense pleasures
> dulls one's spiritual inclination, and the mind ultimately succumbs to
> them unresisting.]

---

These are related to keeping the senses fixed on Meditating on God, without allowing the senses wandering here and there.

Answer (score 2):

Wonderful answers by all.
Just want to add an important point as highlighted by our Guru, His Divine Grace A. C. Bhaktivedanta Swami Prabhupada in the book "Bhagavad Gita As It Is"

> Unless all of the senses are engaged in the service of the Lord, even one of them engaged in sense gratification can deviate the devotee from the path of transcendental advancement.

```
please note "engaged in the service of the Lord"
```

One cannot restrain from engagements, for it is our nature to be always engaged (Verse 3.5). So, one has to put efforts in engaging positive activities of serving Supreme Lord Krsna. Then negative activities will eventually diminish.

One may wonder how to serve Lord? Is it only by visiting temples and offering paraphernalia?
It is stated in Bhakti Rasamrita Sindhu, most detailed literature on Bhakti Yoga that service starts with tongue (*sevonmukhe hi jihvādau (Brs. 1.2.234)*).
Tongue has two to perform, one is to produce sound and taste. Thus, by using it for chanting Lord's holy names and tasting prasadam, sanctified food - one can begin serving Lord.

The mantra prescribed for this age of quarrel and hypocrisy (kali yuga), is the Hare Krsna Maha Mantra or the Great Chant for Deliverance:

**Hare Krsna Hare Krsna Krsna Krsna Hare Hare**

**Hare Rama Hare Rama Rama Rama Hare Hare**

Answer (score 1):

67. One of the moving senses, which the mind follows, steals away the intelligence, as wind moves a boat on the water.

This verse speaks of the faults arising from lack of sense control arising from not absorbing his mind in Krishna.
Among  the uncontrolled senses which move towards sense objects, the mind becomes focused  on one  sense such as the ear or eye.
This one sense followed by the mind leads away the intelligence  concentrated on  atma,  because of the mind’s being attracted to the sense object.
And this is also the case with all the senses.  It is like unfavorable wind taking away a boat being  steered on the water.

One whose mind is fixed on Krishna can become established in atma ie: sthita prajna.
O Arjuna Just as you conquer the enemies, you  should conquer the senses.  From these verses it should be understood  that conquest of the senses takes place spontaneously for the perfected sthita prajna by  absorbing the mind in Bhagavan.
But it will arise from practice for the person aspiring  to attain the state of sthita prajna.